# php Undefined array key

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to import a tsv file where the values have been tab-separated but i keep getting a errror and i dont under why i am getting it the key is in the array

im am using  league/csv with laravel

> `Undefined array key "titleType"`

```
 try {
            $reader = Reader::createFromPath( public_path() . '/' . 'data.tsv', 'r' );
            $reader->setHeaderOffset( 0 );
            $records = Statement::create()->limit( 1 )->process( $reader );
            $records->getHeader();
            foreach ($records as $record) {
                if ( isset( $record[ 'titleType' ] ) && $record[ 'titleType' ] === 'short' || $record[ 'titleType' ] === 'movie' ) {
                    // TODO
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `dump($record)` and see what you get

Comment: can you adjust your `if` conditional to this: 
`if (isset($record['titleType']) && in_array($record['titleType'], ['short', 'movie']))` and see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the OR, make shure the isset is checked AND the second is a OR.

LIke it

```
 try {
        $reader = Reader::createFromPath( public_path() . '/' . 'data.tsv', 'r' );
        $reader->setHeaderOffset( 0 );
        $records = Statement::create()->limit( 1 )->process( $reader );
        $records->getHeader();
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            if ( isset( $record[ 'titleType' ] ) && ($record[ 'titleType' ] === 'short' || $record[ 'titleType' ] === 'movie' )) {
                // TODO
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```